# Simanim in the Rosh

Tags: history, talmud-bavli, rishonim, simanim, rabbeinu-asher

In the Rosh's work found at the back of most gemaras, his halachos are split up into simanim (sections). I am wondering whether we can make inferences from how the simanim are split up and hence want to know who split them up and when. Was it the Rosh himself?

In short, **who set up the system of the different simanim in the commentary of the Rosh to Shas**?

Comment: Do you have reason to suspect he didn’t do it himself?

Comment: @dr shmuel, I am fairly certain that the break up is based on the break up of the kitzor piske harosh, the summary written by the rosh's son, the bal haturim. There is one place where the kitzor pisakim refers to the simonim; I think in shabbos.